# Show image from selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a option list that gets generated through PHP where it lists all the images in one folder. I want to make so when I select an image in the option list the image will be shown above as a preview of what you chose, how do I accomplish that?

```
<img class="imageNews" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <select name="image" id="image" class="form-control">
        <?php
            $files = array_map("htmlspecialchars", scandir("ts"));
            foreach ($files as $file) {
            echo '<option value="'.$file.'" onblur="imageUpdate();">'.$file.'</option>';
            }
        ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
            function imageUpdate(){
            var image=$("select#image").val();
            var path="ts/";
            var src=$("img.imageNews").attr({
            src: path + image,
            title: "Image",
            alt: "Image"
            });
            };
            </script>
    </select><br />
```

When it gets blurred nothing happens but if I open the Console and type "imageUpdate();" it shows the image.

Comment: First you need to open an editor and write some code. Or you if you did, post it in your question.

Comment: install sublime text and try to write something

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Now I have added some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would attach the event to the select and use the onchange instead of onblur.  I don't think you can have the event on the option.

http://jsfiddle.net/n86rY/

```
<img class="imageNews" />
<br />
<br />
<select name="image" id="image" class="form-control" onChange="imageUpdate();">
    <option value="http://placekitten.com/200/300">http://placekitten.com/200/300</option>
    <option value="http://placekitten.com/100/300">http://placekitten.com/100/300</option>
    <option value="http://placekitten.com/100/100">http://placekitten.com/100/100</option>
    <option value="http://placekitten.com/20/100">http://placekitten.com/20/100</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
function imageUpdate() {
    var image = $("select#image").val();
    var path = "ts/";
    var src = $("img.imageNews").attr({
        src: path + image,
        title: "Image",
        alt: "Image"
    });
}
```